# difference between "exec" and "exit" in bash

Tags: bash, exec, exit

I have seen both "exit" and "exec" used in bash script to stop script execution if an error has occurred. For example:

```
if [ ! -f file ]; then
echo "no file"
exit 1
fi
```

and:

```
if [ ! -f file ]; then
exec echo "no file"
fi
```

What is the best practise here and why? Wider discussion/explanations regarding "exec" and "exit" are welcome as well :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`exit` just exits the shell, returning the specified numeric exit code (or 0 if omitted) to the parent process.  It is equivalent to the C library routine also called [`exit`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit), or to returning from `main`.

`exec` *replaces* the shell with a new executable image (still running in the same process), which will in due course exit and return some code or other to the parent process.  It is roughly equivalent to the C library routine [`execvp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp).

Your first example is almost, but not quite, the correct way to stop a script if an error has occurred.  It should read

```
if [ ! -f file ]; then
    echo "no file" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

The `>&2`, which is missing from your example, causes the error message to go to `stderr`, where it belongs, instead of `stdout`, where it does not belong.

Your second example is *wrong*. In addition to the error message going to the wrong place, `exec echo` will stop the script (because `/bin/echo` will do its thing and then exit) but it will return exit code 0 to the parent process.  Exit code 0 means *success*.  Programs running in the Unix environment must always make sure to return a *nonzero* exit code when they have failed.

The proper use of `exec` is in shell scripts that do some set-up work and then invoke a long-lived program written in another language, and don't have anything to do afterward, so there's no point keeping the shell process hanging around.  For example:

```
#! /bin/sh
PATH=/special/directory/for/foo:$PATH
export PATH
exec foo
```

Comment: Zack, thank you for an answer! So you mean _exec_ is mainly used to execute a long-lived program once the shell script has done some housekeeping and/or configuration work for this long-lived program? And program invoked using the _exec_ will take the PID of the script which contained the _exec_? In addition, are there any other popular uses for bash _exec_?

Comment: Ok, but what are the disadvantages/differences if this long-lived program is invoked from the script without _exec_? I mean there will be two PID's in this case and variables set in script will probably have no affect in the long-lived program? Anything else?

Comment: Environment variables inherit to the long-lived program in either case; the only thing that matters there is whether you remembered to `export` them.  Without `exec` there are two PIDs, the shell hangs around taking up RAM, and you have to remember to write `exit $?` on the next line to get the exit code propagated to the grandfather process.  That's it.

Comment: Zack, thank you for explaining! However, it looks like one doesn't need to use `exit $?` anyway? Check those two examples: http://pastebin.com/Sax5SVGa  As you can see, in second example I didn't use exec, but still got the correct exit code. Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: _Sometimes_ the exit code of the last command in the shell script propagates to the parent of the shell, but it is not a thing to be relied on, even if the standards say so.

Comment: As another important feature, running the long-lived process with `exec` makes sure signals are sent to the right process when running under a process supervisor like runit, s6 etc.

Answer (score 3):

The command `exit` exits the current shell with the given exit code.  The command `exec` replaces the current shell by the new process defined by the arguments.  This also effectively terminates the script after the process terminates, the exit code being the exit code of the new process.

The first of your code snippets calls the internal shell command `echo` and then terminates the shell with exit code 1.  The second one replaces the shell by the external program `echo`, which will probably terminate with exit code 0.

I'd definitely recommend the first variant.  It saves launching the external command `/bin/echo` and correctly indicates an error with the exit code.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to indicate an error is for the script to return a non-zero code, like 1.
In your case, the best way is to use "exit 1".

Using "exec" will simply execute the code after it.  Perhaps the examples you've seen are using "#!/bin/bash -e" or "set -e", then using "exec" to call code that fails, thus causing "exec" itself to return a non-zero code, and the "-e" means if any command returns a non-zero code or evaluates to false, exit the script immediately.

Comment: `exec` replaces the current shell by a new process, effectively terminating the script, regardless of `set -e` or similar.